# Categorise groups based on data in long format in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
sample  substance  phenotype  group
1       A          s          X
1       B          s          X
1       C          r          Y
1       D          s          Y
2       A          r          X
2       B          r          X
2       C          s          Y
2       D          s          Y
3       A          r          X
3       B          s          X
3       C          s          Y
3       D          s          Y


structure(list(sample = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
    substance = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", 
    "B", "C", "D"), phenotype = c("s", "s", "r", "s", "r", "r", 
    "s", "s", "r", "s", "s", "s"), group = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", 
    "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "Y", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

What I want to do is to summarise per sample the phenotype for each group, based on the values I find within the phenotype column for each substance within that group. That means, for each group, if "r" is present in the column "phenotype" for that sample, the phenotype for the group will be "r", otherwise "s".

E.g. here I want to end up with a dataset that looks like this:

```
sample  group  res
1       X      s
1       Y      r
2       X      r
2       Y      s
3       X      r
3       Y      s
```

So far I have tried the follwing:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
 group_by(sample,group) %>%
 mutate(res = ifelse(grepl("r", phenotype), "r", "s")
```

However, this only works per row, instead of per group.

Comment: try `ifelse(any(phenotype == "r"), "r", "s")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach

```
> aggregate(phenotype~sample+group,data=df,FUN="min")
  sample group phenotype
1      1     X         s
2      2     X         r
3      3     X         r
4      1     Y         r
5      2     Y         s
6      3     Y         s
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df%>%
group_by(sample, group) %>%
summarize(res = ifelse("r" %in% phenotype, "r", "s"), .groups = 'drop')


sample group res  
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1      1 X     s    
2      1 Y     r    
3      2 X     r    
4      2 Y     s    
5      3 X     r    
6      3 Y     s
```